# How do i insert values for Bool in my insert values command?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line

Gender is a Bool value but i dont know how to insert its value
Below is what i have written

> INSERT INTO users
>     (user_id, user_name, joined, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender)
>   VALUES
>     ('150/08', 'Otollo', NOW(), SHA('WUODBABA'), 'Joshua', 'Abuto', '1998-08-23',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `TRUE` or `FALSE` as below

```
INSERT INTO users 
(user_id, user_name, joined, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender) 
VALUES 
('150/08', 'Otollo', NOW(), SHA('WUODBABA'), 'Joshua', 'Abuto', '1998-08-23',TRUE)
```

[**Here you can find more information**](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/bool)

Comment: If i say true will it say male? and how can i confirm or change that?

Comment: `If i say true will it say male?` I don't know it's your DB :) `how can i confirm or change that? ` what do you mean confirm? You can change it using `FALSE` insetad.

Answer (score 0):

use true and false such as

```
INSERT INTO users 
(user_id, user_name, joined, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender) 
VALUES 
('150/08', 'Otollo', NOW(), SHA('WUODBABA'), 'Joshua', 'Abuto', '1998-08-23',TRUE)
```

and also use this link to check all possible way to insert bool value

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply this.

I don't know what datatype you are having for that gender column.

**I am assuming that your column datatype is bit**

you just need to pass 0 & 1 in the database for gender column.

```
  INSERT INTO users 
    (user_id, user_name, joined, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender) 
    VALUES 
    ('150/08', 'Otollo', NOW(), SHA('WUODBABA'), 'Joshua', 'Abuto', '1998-08-23',0 OR 1)
```